# Can this sql-statement be shortened?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this SQL query to a PostgreSQL database. Can it be shortened? I am thinking about the **where** part.

```
SELECT *
FROM reservations
WHERE (starts_at BETWEEN ? AND ?) OR (ends_at BETWEEN ? AND ?)
```

The values for the question-marks is:

- The beginning of the current date in datetime format
- The end of the the current date in datetime format
- Same as point one
- Same as point two

The code is meant to return all the reservations that begins or ends on a certain date. And works as it is supposed to. But I have to supply the same information multiple times into the query.

**I so not actually use this exactly SQL, so there might be an obvious error somewhere, but please focus on the where part**

Comment: WHERE DATE(start_a)=? OR DATE(ends_at)=? is a few characers shorter but performance sucks.

Comment: Interesting. I am gonna stick with what I got then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't improve upon this.

```
WHERE (starts_at BETWEEN ? AND ?) OR (ends_at BETWEEN ? AND ?)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a huge fan of `BETWEEN` in this context, because `timestamp`or `datetime` can be fractional.  In particular, specifying the last possible value on a given date is much more complicated than specifying the first possible value (midnight) because you have to specify the time as 23:59:59.999... out to whatever precision your RDBMS uses.  PostgreSQL's `timestamp` is supposed to be accurate to the microsecond (1e-6 seconds), for example, so it's easy to specify a range that either includes times you don't want, or misses times that you do.

On the other hand, if you use `BETWEEN` with midnight of the following day so you don't have to know the precision of the time, you're including a time that doesn't exist in the date you're interested in.  If your application is only precise to the second, or the minute, or to 5 minutes, then you may mis-categorize data or, worse, count it twice since it suddenly counts as being in two dates.

I would prefer:

```
WHERE (starts_at >= ? AND starts_at < ?) 
    OR (ends_at >= ? AND ends_at < ?)
```

Where the `?` map to:

1. Midnight of the target date.
2. Midnight of the date after the target date.
3. Midnight of the target date.
4. Midnight of the date after the target date.

It's not as short, but it's decidedly safer unless you really want to specify your intervals that precisely.

However, you should *not* do the following, even though it's shorter:

```
WHERE DATE(starts_at) = ?
    OR DATE(ends_at) = ?
```

You don't want to do that because it's not [SARGEable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

This is also an example of why shortness or brevity is a poor measure of code quality.  Generally, I'd order my preference like so:

1. Accuracy.
2. Performance.
3. Readability/maintainability.
4. Brevity.